# Spinner Shows Black Color

Tags: java, android

I have a problem regarding the spinner design. I am using this code to generate a dropdown spinner:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

    ArrayList < String > spinnerArray = new ArrayList < String > ();
    spinnerArray.add("one");
    spinnerArray.add("two");
    spinnerArray.add("three");
    spinnerArray.add("four");
    spinnerArray.add("five");

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter < String > spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    layout.addView(spinner);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

It displays this:
[image]

How can I remove the black color that blocks the spinner?

Comment: You are adding the Spinner manually so try to add background colour to it

Comment: I changed the background color to white, but it's not showing the arrow pointing down. I think the background color covers the arrow.

Comment: Did you try using the property of adapter **setDropDownViewResource** ?

Comment: Yes, it's still the same.

Comment: where are you setting height and width in that?

Comment: I tried setting height and width with spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); but still not fixing the problem

Comment: you did not set the width, height and orientation of your linear layout

Comment: I also set the width, height, and orientation of the linearlayout, but it's still the same.

Comment: your code works fine for me.. probably that is styling issues you are facing. btw what `activity_my` contains?

Answer (score 2):

```
layout.addView(spinner);
setContentView(layout);
```

When you dynamically add the view to the layout. you are missing some configuration. thats the reason you see a black box.

try the below code:

xml:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

activity:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            arraydata, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Is there no way of creating it with just code (not in xml)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout file simple_list.xml in your layout folder:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="Sample Text"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And refer this in arrayadapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.simple_list, spinnerArray);
```

**Update 1** Add this:

> spinner.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),android.R.color.white));

**update 2**
Instead of using constraint use Linear once in your layout file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LineartLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity"> </LinearLayout>
```

Set id to LinearLayout (your root view), then use `findViewById` for this view and add spinner to this rootView and remove `setContentView(layout);`
Change it like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
spinnerArray.add("one");
spinnerArray.add("two");
spinnerArray.add("three");
spinnerArray.add("four");
spinnerArray.add("five");

Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

layout.addView(spinner);

setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: The problem is still there.

Comment: Why you didn't used spinner in layout (activity_my)?

Comment: I have changed my answer please check

Comment: I wanted to create it programmatically because it's dynamic.

Comment: I added this: spinner.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),android.R.color.white)); but still the same

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly your code worked for me. So make sure that there is no element there or some other piece of code related to theme or colors.  [image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: may be theme ans style issue

Answer (score 0):

Add a linearlayout to your activity_my layout and name it linearLayoutContainer . Then get a reference to it from code.

```
LinearLayout container = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutContainer);

Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);

container.addView(spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);

spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```